# Are load testing results affected by location, e.g. India vs. USA

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am working on load testing in one of e-commerce websites mean while I came across one question i.e.,

I am doing the load testing from India. Whether it will be having any changes in results if  I do load testing from USA.

Note :
By considering the same environment and application is on live server.

Comment: Most probably no. High bandwidth could change result but that will be minor. Mostly you will get same result.

Comment: What are you load testing? Application infrastructure or response times?

Comment: @HelpingHands Is that an answer or a comment? #nazimods

Comment: @corsiKa - It is not descriptive so I put as comment.

Answer (score 12):

It is very likely you will get differing results.  Especially in response times.  This is mainly due to latency caused by the Geographical distribution.  This will become important if response times is one of the metrics you are using to understand the website's ability to cope/scale under load.

A simple reflection of this is;

go to http://amazon.co.uk/
and compare it to http://amazon.co.jp/

You can see the differences in "hops" it makes to reach the server and the latency caused by opening a CMD window (on windows) and entering the following command

```
tracert amazon.co.jp
```

followed by

```
tracert amazon.co.uk
```

The important thing to remember is that your load tests are comparisons of like for like.  Running one load test from India and another from the USA means you are comparing differing setups which may lead to confusion in interpreting the results.  If you run them all from India, conceptually that's fine, but (I'm guessing) the main users would be US based. I would therefore recommend running the tests from US servers if you can.

Services such as [Blazemeter](https://blazemeter.com/) offer this functionality (as a service).  You can also achieve similar if you run your existing JMeter suite from a remote location. For example, by running it from an AWS instance in that local (US East (Northern Virginia)).

Comment: ,Thanks for answer . My application is having more number of users in USA.So it's better to do load testing on Application from USA ?.If yes ,then how can I achieve this from using JMeter.

Comment: Either you can make an AWS (or Cloud) instance in a US district and run your suite on that or Blazemeter allows you to run your own JMeter from US servers.

Answer (score 1):

It will. According to [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) JMeter's "Response Time" is actual server's response time + latency and when application under test and JMeter are on different world's ends it'll take some time for request to reach the server, same for the response.

See [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) as an evidence of the Latency metric importance.